# Linq Query modification to include a value in a related table

Tags: c#, linq, join, include

I need to modify a linq query to include a value from a foreign key related table.
The original query is:

```
var query = from n in context.Observations
                        select n;
```

I have another table ObservationsScreening that's 1-many to Observations, and contains a ObservationsGuid field.
I want to include the field "Status" from ObservationsScreening table, but if there is no ObservationsScreening record for a Observation, I still want to return the data for Observations.
I have tried using a join like this:

```
var query = from n in context.Observations join s in context.ObservationScreenings on n.GUID equals s.ObservationGuid
                        select n;
```

But I am not able to get the value I'm needing when I attempt to populate my DTO:

```
SortablePaginatedList<DTO.ObservationReportObservation> results = new SortablePaginatedList<DTO.ObservationReportObservation>(query.Select(u => new DTO.ObservationReportObservation()
                 {
                     ObservationGuid = u.GUID,
                     CarrierName = u.CompanyName,
                     DOTNumber = u.DOTNumber,
                     KYUNumber = u.KYUNumber,
                     Status = u.Verified ? "Verified" : "Unverified",
                     TestResult = u.ObservationScreenings.Status,
                     ObservedBy = u.ObservedBy,
                     WeighStation = u.WeighStation.Name,
                     ObservedDate = u.ObservedDate,
                     VehiclePlateNumber = u.VehiclePlateNumber
                 }), Page, PageSize, SortBy, Ascending);
```

I'm getting a message "Sytem.Collections.Generic.Icollection does not contain a definition for Status and no extension method.
Observation report observation class is:

```
public class ObservationReportObservation
{
    public Guid ObservationGuid { get; set; }
    public string CarrierName { get; set; }
    public int? DOTNumber { get; set; }
    public string KYUNumber { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string TestResult { get; set; }
    public string ObservedBy { get; set; }
    public string WeighStation { get; set; }
    public DateTime ObservedDate { get; set; }
    public string VehiclePlateNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Note that there are 2 statuses. The one in the class that is actually called status is referring to a different field, and it is working correctly. TestResult (which is also called status in the ObservationScreening table) is the field I am adding.
Does any one have any suggestion on how I can do this? Include maybe?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is saying that there is simply no `Status` method/property in your `DTO.ObservationReportObservation` class. Maybe you're missing something and/or it's a syntax error and your method begins with e.g. lower case letter or something like that? You may consider sharing the constructor code of that class so that we can help you further.

Comment: can you write your ObservationScreenings Class?

Comment: "*ObservationsScreening that's 1-many to Observations** From what I see, it's the opposite. So `u.ObservationScreenings` is a collection, which is also indicated by the error message.

Comment: I edit the question above to include the constructor class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

> I have another table ObservationsScreening that's 1-many to Observations

Looking at the name of the navigation property (`u.ObservationScreenings`) and the error message, it should be the opposite, i.e. **one** `Observation` may have **zero or more** `ObservationScreenings`.

> I want to include the field "Status" from ObservationsScreening table, but if there is no ObservationsScreening record for a Observation, I still want to return the data for Observations

So you are looking for a [Left Outer Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)

> I have tried using a join like this

There is no need to use manual joins when you have **navigation** properties. Use the navigation properties and EF will create the necessary joins for you.

Based on the above, I think you are seeking for something like this:

```
var query = 
    from o in context.Observations
    from s in u.ObservationScreenings.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new DTO.ObservationReportObservation
    {
        ObservationGuid = o.GUID,
        CarrierName = o.CompanyName,
        DOTNumber = o.DOTNumber,
        KYUNumber = o.KYUNumber,
        Status = o.Verified ? "Verified" : "Unverified",
        TestResult = s.Status,
        ObservedBy = o.ObservedBy,
        WeighStation = o.WeighStation.Name,
        ObservedDate = o.ObservedDate,
        VehiclePlateNumber = o.VehiclePlateNumber
    };

var results = new SortablePaginatedList<DTO.ObservationReportObservation>(
    query, Page, PageSize, SortBy, Ascending);
```

Note the `DefaultIfEmpty` call - this what makes the `left outer join`. Without including it the query will be translated to `inner join`